# Connection to Gazepoint

Tags: php, matlab, tcp

[GazePoint](http://gazept.com/) is an eye tracker tool. It uses TCP protocol for connection. I want to connect to it using PHP. I wrote a simple PHP code, but it hangs on `fgets`. I also used [packetsender](https://packetsender.com/) for sending and receiving packets, but I only receive empty packets in response. The point is that I have a MatLab code that works fine with Gazepoint. I wonder what the problem is!

Matlab code:

```
classdef gazept < handle
properties(SetAccess=public)
    ip_address        
    port_number
    client_socket
    gx
    gy
end
methods

    function obj = connect(obj, ip, portnum)    
        if nargin < 2, ip = '127.0.0.1'; end
        if nargin < 3, portnum = 4242; end           
        obj.ip_address=ip;
        obj.port_number = portnum;
        try        
            obj.client_socket = tcpip(obj.ip_address, obj.port_number);
            set(obj.client_socket, 'InputBufferSize', 4096); 
            fopen(obj.client_socket);     
            obj.client_socket.Terminator = 'CR/LF';                            
            gazepoint_info = strcat('Connected to:', obj.ip_address, ' on port:', num2str(obj.port_number), '\n');  
            fprintf(gazepoint_info);
        catch err        
            rethrow(err);
            fprintf('Make sure GazepointControl is open on host machine.');
        end
    end

    function obj = calibrate(obj,delay)
        if nargin < 2, delay = 15; end
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="CALIBRATE_SHOW" STATE="1" />');
        pause(10);
        while (get(obj.client_socket, 'BytesAvailable') > 0)                                 
            results = fscanf(obj.client_socket)
            pause(.01);
        end
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="CALIBRATE_START" STATE="1" />');

        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="CALIBRATE_SHOW" STATE="0" />');
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="CALIBRATE_START" STATE="0" />');
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<GET ID="CALIBRATE_RESULT_SUMMARY" />');
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_DATA" STATE="0" />');
        pause(delay);
        while (get(obj.client_socket, 'BytesAvailable') > 0)
            results = fscanf(obj.client_socket)
            pause(.01);
        end
        pause(1);
        fprintf(obj.client_socket, '<SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_DATA" STATE="1" />');
    end
```

PHP code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 4242, $erro, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br /><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "connected to 127.0.0.1:4242<br/>";
        $out = '<GET ID="CALIBRATE_SHOW" />';
        $res = fwrite($fp, $out);
        echo "res: " . $res . "<br/>";
        sleep(5);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
I needed to add CR/LF to the end of the packet. I didn't know what is CR/LF. I only added .chr(13).chr(10) to the end of the packet. chr(13) is CR and chr(10) is LF. New code is like this:

```
$fp = fsockopen("172.16.146.203", 4242, $erro, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br /><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "connected to 127.0.0.1:4242<br/>";
        $delay = 15;
        $out = '<GET ID="CALIBRATE_SHOW" />'.chr(13).chr(10);
        $res = fwrite($fp, $out);
        echo "res: " . $res . "<br/>";
        sleep(5);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo fgets($fp, 128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```